# Adding Section Headers to UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Forgive the noob question, still learning.

I have a UITableView with a single array for data (approx 50). I'm looking to implement section headers but I just can't get my head around it. All the information I can find seems to vary greatly (there seems to be manes ways it can be implemented?) and I can't seem to piece it all together!

As ever I can't make out the Apple docs but I think that's down to my inexperience.

So a few questions:

I understand I need to state how many sections are needed, with a single array, would would be the best way?

Can I use a single array? Or am I going to need to break it down into numerous arrays, each with their own section?

Thanks in advance.

Code for cellForRowAtIndexPath for jonkroll

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:row+3];
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[tableViewArray objectAtIndex:row+17];
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol let you to define how the tableView renders your data.

Use `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` to tell your table how many sections it will have.

Use `numberOfRowsInSection:` to tell your table how many rows will be in each section.

Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to tell your table what to render in a particular cell based on indexPath (indexPath is a structure that identifies a particular cell based on section and row)

So you say you have a single array that you want to display in more than one section.  This is a very contrived example, but let's say you want rows 1-30 to be in the first section and rows 31-50 to be in the second section.

You can do the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0: return 30; break;
        case 1: return 20; break;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int section = [indexPath section];
    int row = [indexPath row];

    NSString* CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[array objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[array objectAtIndex:row+30];
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. I've implemented this into my code and I've successfully implemented headers. However, using your code as a base, the sections seem to repeat. For example, Section 0 has 3 rows, row 1, row 2, row 3, Section 1 has 4 rows but the data is displayed as row 1, row 2, row 3, row 4, rather than starting at row 4 and going row 4, row 5, row 6, row 7. This is the same for all subsequent sections. Any ideas? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, in the `switch` statement based on the section, are you adding 3 to the array index?  The idea here is that the indexPath for the first cell in your second section is (section=1, row=0), and the second cell in that section is (section=1, row=1), etc.  So you need to add an offset to get the correct range from your array when rendering the cells for the second section.

Comment: Is that the part where you put cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)[array objectAtIndex:row+30];? If so, I'm sure I have, although I'll have to double check. There 7 sections at the moment to I might of fudged something.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Can you post the code you are using to set the textLabel text?

Comment: I've added the code to the original question, still can't find where I'm going wrong. :S

Comment: Are you setting the local variable `section` to the value from `[indexPath section]`?  If not, your switch statement will always think it is displaying cells for the first section.

Comment: Yeah, int section = [indexPath section]; is in there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6669/discussion-between-jonkroll-and-mattfllr)

Comment: You could just as well make an nsarray that has two arrays inside. each array corresponds to each index. then that index array has rows. Works if your content is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You application probably has an [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) and [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate) (this is where you return the elements of the array and configure the number of sections, etc.). Within that class (or those classes if they're separate) there's two approaches you can take depending on what you'd like to do.

If you just want to have a **title with the default look**, implement `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` to return the title you want for each section.

If you want a **custom view**, implement `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` as well as `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` to return the custom view along with the height of the header views.

Comment: Thanks, got that bit. What about implementing the headers? So 'if (section == 0) { return @"Header";' blah blah, how do I define where the section starts and finishes, if that makes sense.

Comment: There's a few ways to do that. Is your array dynamic, or is it hard-coded? If it's hard-coded you could make it so you have one array per section and hardcode the titles to those sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a header consider using a UITableViewCustomCell, drag one into the nib where you have your tableView set up. Declare and link up in InterfaceBuilder.

```
    IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellOne;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellOne;
```

Then you can use to assign the CellView to the Table view for your header.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if ([array count] == 0) return cellone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the iPhoneCoreDataRecipes example that Apple puts out.  They use a Tableview and show the data different ways.  Being new at programming myself, I don't know how to provide the link to you, but it's in the iOS 5.0 Library under Data Management.